# Why we call it function expression? : Js

Tags: javascript, function

We know that an expression is any piece of code that evaluates in a way we can say to a single value in Js, so it can perform a calculation in order to get the value or it can already be the value so the final product, so knowing this why we refer to this type of function that can be store in a variable as a function expression? So if we think this when we run this:

```
const calcAge = function (birthYear) {
  return 2037 - birthYear;
 };
```

this only creates the function, this actually doesn't perform any calculation in order to produce a value, and expression would be the function call cause this process at the end is a single value, so? or is it that the function itself is the value? what really mean the word "expression" in this definition? please someone can clarify this to me, thanks!

Comment: A function expression is an expression whose value is a function, just as a numeric expression is an expression whose value is a number.

Comment: Literals like `'something'` or `10` are expressions as well hence a function that can be assigned to a variable is an expression

Comment: Probably a better term would be "function literal", but that's not what caught on.

Comment: Like the above comments, and also if it makes it easier for you an expression is a piece of code that can be assigned to a variable and it can be passed around, but the whole declaration `const calcAge = function...` is a statement. A statement has placeholders for expression(s). A statement doesn't return/evaluate to a value. An expression evaluates to a value. You can use `calcAge`'s value - *a function expression* - and pass it as argument (*callback fn*) to a FN, ex.: `console.log()` it. But, you can't use a statement as an argument, because again, it doesn't executes/evaluates to a value.

Comment: Relevant docs: [Expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Comment: If to answer your exact question is that:if function-expression call returns yet another value/expression it doesn't make it less of an expression.Like you can use an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) and it's still an expression. That aside, the passing it as argument helped me when I once struggled why I couldn't use `if` statement in my `{}` in React's JSX but I could use *ternary operator* it's that it gets executed right away similarly to IIFE, hence why the *ternary operator* is able to be used in JSX's JS-expression placeholders (`{}`) the same way it can be used as FN arg.

Comment: "*this only creates the function, this actually doesn't perform any calculation in order to produce a value*" - that *is* performing operations to produce the function.

Comment: "*what really mean the word "expression" in this definition?*" - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science)

Answer (score -2):

Basically this would define same function but in different way - this naming, that is confusing - **function expression** - simply means (quote form MDN with link)

> The **function** keyword can be used to define a function inside an
> **expression**

[MDN #1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)

And other way to declare function - **function declarations**

> The **function** declaration defines a function with the specified
> parameters.

[MDN #2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)

E.g. all the functions here same - the difference is the way of declaration

Hope that helps to clarify

Comment: *'all the functions here same - the difference is the way of declaration'* This isn't accurate and the links you've provided explain those differences. Most notably, [function expressions aren't hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#function_expression_hoisting).